# Convert Excel 2003 workbook to pdf Sheet wise

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2005, ms-office

again i am killing your time. I have to make an app which convert workbook to pdf
i am using PDF995. But I dont know how to configure the paper size as some of sheets takes about 150 inches. Also it is not converting sheetwise. I want that it create pdf as per sheet name.
Following is the code sample i am using.

```
Dim objExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim objWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim totalWorkSheets As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

Public Sub PrintByName(ByVal s As Worksheet)


    Dim myprinter As String
    Dim printer_name As String
    printer_name = "PDF995"


    If System.IO.Directory.Exists("D:\" + objWorkBook.Name) Then
    Else
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\" + objWorkBook.Name)
    End If

    myprinter = objExcel.ActivePrinter
    objExcel.ActivePrinter = printer_name
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    s.PrintOut(Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:=printer_name, PrintToFile:=True,PrToFileName:=s.Name) 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500)
    objExcel.ActivePrinter = myprinter
End Sub
```

I know that the file name i am passing will not work, but i cant get a way for this.
Also how should i configure paper size etc. I have tasted many trials app , but most of them are giving error like can not open the excel or run time error etc. I think this might be due to link in workbook. Can any one tell me how  correct this code and configure papersize etc as well.
Thanks in advance ..........